# Android MMS Monitoring

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, mms, multimedia

I have spent the last several hours trying to research this and understand it, however i've come up empty on every example I tried. Basically my app can send information via MMS to someone else, though the content is in a format that the native inbox doesn't display correctly.

Sending the content works fine, however I need to be able to detect the incoming MMS message and open the content in my application to format it correctly. Are there any decent tutorials for this? Of the ones i've found it seems like there's a good amount of information that is missing so I usually end up with errors, or missing libraries.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 1):

There is no official way to receive MMS in Android. However, clever people have, through source-code inspection, devised ways to read SMS and MMS messages: [How to Read MMS Data in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012287/how-to-read-mms-data-in-android/6446831#6446831)

Comment: I saw that listing, however is there an easy way to say display the list of MMS Messages in a similar fasion to the native Inbox? I'm fairly new too Android development and it has certainly been a challenge. Basically, it seems like in that source if i'm not mistaken, you query the phones MMS data, then get a list of MMS Messages, but I do not necessarily want to look through all of them, say only the most recent

Comment: There is no UI control that looks like message coversation list in Messages app. This is custom made. Also when you query provider data you can set some conditions. See `ContentResolver.query(..)`, especially parameter "selection".

Comment: SO i've tried to follow that link again, and i've implemented a class that should go through and save the ID's of the MMS messages to an array, however when I know I have at least 3 MMS messages on my device, I still only get a listing of 1? Any ideas?

Comment: Detecting incoming MMS and querying the MMS content provider are two different things.  I think the OP was asking about detecting incoming MMS.  The SO post you gave a link to, just does the querying of the MMS content provider.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very useful link:

[AndDev.org:Where can I find information about sending/receiving MMS](http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/where-can-i-find-information-about-sending-receiving-mms-t51284.html)

Here incoming MMS are detected using ContentObserver.

Comment: I've seen this one before, however I couldn't get it work correctly. There were things in the code I couldn't correct or import or figure out, it wouldn't compile.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work either.  Where is the `ServiceController` class implemented?