# Android MMS observer

Tags: android, mms

I have the following code:

```
public class MmsObserver extends ContentObserver {
    private Context context;

    public MmsObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
        this.context = service.getBaseContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);

        Long largestDateCounted = Long.parseLong(UserPreferencesManager.getInstance().getValueFromPreferences(context, context.getString(R.string.preferences_current_counter), "0"));
        String filter = "creator != ? and date > ?";
        String[] args = new String[]{context.getPackageName(), Long.toString(largestDateCounted)};
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(Constants.Mms, null, filter, args, null);

        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            c.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to observe when user sends/receives an MMS message. However, my observer never gets called. Is there something I'm missing on this? I have read the below:

[Android MMS Monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311628/android-mms-monitoring)

[Android MMS Broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151749/android-mms-broadcast-receiver)

**EDIT**

here is how i'm running the observer:

```
mmsContent = new MmsObserver(new Handler());
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Constants.Mms, true, mmsContent);
```

Comment: How exactly are you registering the Observer? Are you certain your `Service` (presumably) is running when the changes occur?

Comment: I updated my question. Yes, service is running and I have an SMS observer which is also always running (and working).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was asking mainly for the specific `Uri` you're using. It needs to be `content://mms-sms/`, at least on older versions. I've not dug through the source to find out why, but for some reason, `content://mms/` won't work for a `ContentObserver`. Do note that that's going to fire for SMS, too.

Comment: That was correct! I will accept your answer if you put it below.

Comment: whats strange is that on some phones `content://mms-sms/` doesn't work. At least when querying for new messages. On Galaxy S6 it didn't work. Will have to test this on that device.

Comment: The query should work with `content://mms/`. You just need to register the Observer with `content://mms-sms/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When registering a `ContentObserver` for MMS, the URI needs to be `content://mms-sms/`, at least on older Android versions. For some reason, `content://mms/` won't work for a `ContentObserver`, other than possibly firing on changes to draft messages.

Do note that this will cause the Observer to fire for changes to the SMS table, as well.

Comment: Hi Mike, you have answered a few of my questions on SO and wanted to ask you something. I have a project here: https://github.com/kalvish21/AndroidMessenger, my goal is to create a desktop client for an Android app that can do SMS and MMS from desktop. I want to open source it and make it free. Are you interested in helping out? The mac client is almost done. Basic UI improvements will happen on Android app.

Comment: Next step is desktop client for Windows and Linux.

Comment: Please reply either way, would love to hear from you.

Comment: Hi, there! I'd love to help, but I don't have access to an actual development machine, at the moment. I've been doing minor stuff directly on my mobile devices for a while, but I can't really do anything for desktop. I'll keep a bookmark to your stuff, though, and give you a shout if I ever get setup again. Good luck with your project! Sounds like fun. Cheers!