# Integrating MMS in android application

Tags: android, mms

I have found few examples in stackoverflow for integrating MMS with my android application. But nothing worked fine.

If some one can send me a good link for MMS integration in my application, i shall be very much thankful.

Looking forward for your response.

Thank you.

Comment: i need code for android MMS and SMS in same application. Can any1 suggest me a good link where i can find the working code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For reading mms: [How to Read MMS Data in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012287/how-to-read-mms-data-in-android)

For writing mms try using this example: http://maximbogatov.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/mms-in-android-part-2-working-with-mms-storage/

It adds the mmsdata to the tables, but there is still an issue with the message not showing in the native message application.

Hopefully this will get you started on the right track anyway.