# Android: what to do with application/smil MIME type

Tags: android, mms

I am using code similar to another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6446831/652738).  But my MIME type for every MMS is "application/smil".  How do I determine if the MMS contains a picture, audio, text, etc?

Here is the code I am using at the moment:

```
        String selectionPart = "mid =" + id;
        Uri ur = Uri.parse("content://mms/part");
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(ur, null, selectionPart, null, null);
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String[] values = new String[cur.getColumnCount()];

                for (int i = 0; i < cur.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    values[i] = cur.getString(i);
                }

                String partId = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                String type = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("ct"));
```

This is what is contained in values String[] for an audio MMS:

```
[56, 98, -1, application/smil, smil.xml, null, null, null, <0000>, smil.xml, null, null, null, <smil>
<smil>
  <head>
    <layout>
      <root-layout height="480px" width="320px"/>
      <region fit="meet" height="160px" id="Text" left="0" top="320" width="320px"/>
    </layout>
  </head>
  <body>
    <par dur="11000ms">
      <audio dur="11000ms" src="cid:171"/>
      <text region="Text" src="cid:172"/>
    </par>
  </body>
</smil>
]
```

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556633/parse-application-smil-mms-mime-type-on-android

Comment: There is an excellent description of how to access images and text in MMS messages at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012287/how-to-read-mms-data-in-android.

Answer (score 18):

The problem is that you're assuming that your cursor only has 1 entry. It actually does not.

For MMS messages, you will find that there are 3 (or more) entries corresponding to the same `mid`. They are described below:

1. One entry will correspond to the SMIL file. SMIL is a file format containing xml that helps an MMS viewer to know how to display the MMS (this is what you have printed above). The MIME type for this entry is `application/smil` if you look at the column called `ct` (acronym for content type)
2. Another entry will correspond to the text file that contains any text within that MMS besides the attachment. The MIME type of this will be `text/plain`
3. Lastly, you will find another entry that actually has the attachment. This attachment can have a variety of different MIME types depending on what the file is. If it happens to be a jpeg it will be `image/jpeg`, if png it will be `image/png` etc... (you get the point)

So, the problem was that you were assuming that the cursor has 1 row returned. If you iterate through 3 rows you will find what you are looking for

Typically, I would filter the `_data` column for non-empty value to get to the attachment row right away. (The `_data` column will contain the uri path for where the attachment is saved on the phone. That row will be `null` for all other rows that do not correspond to the MMS attachment. So you must search for the row that matches your `mid` and where `_data column value is not null`) When you find that row, you can just read the `ct` column of that row to find the MIME type of the row. That will tell you what type of file is being transferred in the MMS message be it `image/xyz` or `audio/abc` or `video/qwe` etc...

Comment: It is very nicely explained.