# How to get MMS id Android Application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, mms

can anyone help me out to find MMS id, i using  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012287/how-to-read-mms-data-in-android/6446831#6446831) code to get MMS text but i don't know the MMS id (mmsId) so i stopped !!

I'll be thankful for your help

Samila

Comment: i am also having similar issue,let me know once you get solution

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri mmsInboxUri = Uri.parse("content://mms");               
Cursor mmsInboxCursor = getContentResolver().query(mmsInboxUri ,new String[]     
    {"_id","msg_box","ct_t","date"}, "msg_box=1 or msg_box=2", null, null);
int count = mmsInboxCursor.getCount(); 
if(mmsInboxCursor != null){

    try{

         if (mmsInboxCursor.moveToFirst())
         {                  
            do{

                System.out.println("<====MONITORING MESSAGES====>");                                
                int id = mmsInboxCursor.getString(0); 
              }while(mmsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("MMSMonitor :: startMMSMonitoring Exception== "+ e.getMessage());
    }
}
```