# Incoming MMSs are not detected in Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, sms, mms

I am working on an Android app that is supposed to detect incoming SMSs and MMSs and do some follow-up operations. I was able to implement the SMS part without any problem but when it comes to MMS, the app is not detecting them.

I have the following lines in the Manifest file:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.library.MmsReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER"
                android:priority="1" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Also, I am asking for the following permissions for MMS:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
```

The receiver class is declared in the following way:

```
class MmsReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d(MmsReceiver::class.java.simpleName, "onReceive: MMS RECEIVED")
    }
}
```

When I receive an MMS message, I expect to see the above log in the console, but nothing is shown.

I looked over other posts on StackOverflow like [Detecting MMS messages on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329819/detecting-mms-messages-on-android), [Sending and Receiving SMS and MMS in Android (pre Kit Kat Android 4.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-sms-and-mms-in-android-pre-kit-kat-android-4-4) or [How to read incoming MMS and SMS messages on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63194135/how-to-read-incoming-mms-and-sms-messages-on-android) but nothing helped.

Am I missing any configuration steps? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents#wap_push_deliver_action) say:

WAP_PUSH_DELIVER_ACTION
Broadcast Action: A new WAP PUSH message has been received by the device. **This intent will only be delivered to the default sms app.**

Try this:

WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED_ACTION
Broadcast Action: A new WAP PUSH message has been received by the device. **This intent will be delivered to all registered receivers** as a notification.

Comment: I have tried your solution but it's still not working.