# Reading mms details programmatically and display in listview

Tags: android, cursor, mms

i need to get all the MMS Data detalis like mms_image, address,date and type. 
    i am using following logic. In this i am using two cursors, one for images and other for remaining fields. but the size of two cursors are different. so, i am unable to match both image and other fields.

```
              //for date,address,type
         Cursor curPdu = getContentResolver ().query(Uri.parse("content://mms"), null, null, null, null);
                     while(curPdu.moveToNext())
                       {
                            String id = curPdu.getString (curPdu.getColumnIndex ("_id"));
                            String date = curPdu.getString (curPdu.getColumnIndex ("date"));
                            mms_add.add(getAddressNumber(Integer.parseInt(id)));

                            int type = Integer.parseInt(curPdu.getString(curPdu.getColumnIndex("m_type")));
                           mms_type.add((type==128)?"2":"1");
                           mms_date.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(date)));

                        }

 //for image
            Cursor curPart = getContentResolver (). query (Uri.parse ("content://mms/part"), null, null, null, null);
              while(curPart.moveToNext())
                  {
                  coloumns = curPart.getColumnNames();
                    if(values == null)
                    values = new String[coloumns.length];

                    for(int i=0; i< curPart.getColumnCount(); i++)
                    {
                    values[i] = curPart.getString(i);
                    }

                        if(values[3].equals("image/jpeg"))
                        {
                        mms_image.add(GetMmsAttachment(values[0],values[12],values[4]));
                        }else{
                            mms_image.add("null");
                        }
                }
```

so, please guide me how to get all the details using one cusor if possible.

Comment: You can try using the code in this library: https://github.com/klinker41/android-smsmms/

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution and url provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087972/receiving-mms-in-android-application/10088262#10088262).
And may i know why you need 2 cursor ? I assume there is some mms without image attached so that's the reason you get a different count.