# Created MMS message in my app, but does not show in native message application

Tags: android, mms

I created mms message.
The problem is: that is showed in my app, but that does not show in android native message application.
Do you have an idea what can be wrong? What should I set for the thread_id?
Thanks in advance.

--- Here is my code ---

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(); 
cv.put("thread_id", System.currentTimeMillis() % 100); 
cv.put("ct_t", "application/vnd.wap.multipart.related");
cv.put("read", "1"); 
Uri temp_mms = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://mms/inbox"), cv); 
String str_uri = temp_mms.toString(); 
String newID = temp_mms.getLastPathSegment().trim();

 ContentValues cv_addr2 = new ContentValues(); 
 cv_addr2.put("address", "112233"); 
 Uri temp_mms_addr2 = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://mms/"+ newID +"/addr"), cv_addr2); 

 // ------------------------------PART Table ContentValues 
 Uri uriPart = Uri.parse("content://mms/"+ newID +"/part");
 ContentValues cv_part2 = new ContentValues(); 
 cv_part2.put("ct", "image/jpeg"); 
 Uri temp_mms_part2 = cr.insert(uriPart, cv_part2);

 OutputStream os = cr.openOutputStream(temp_mms_part2);
 InputStream is = cr.openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
 byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
 for (int len = 0; (len = is.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
     os.write(buffer, 0, len);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: not sure why it isn't showing up in the built-in messaging app, but check out the answer to [How to Read MMS Data in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012287/how-to-read-mms-data-in-android) for how to get a thread id.

Edit: you also might need to add an address entry into `content://mms/{id}/addr` for the sender, and if this is coming from the current device, it seems like `insert-address-token` is enough. Address entries also need a `type` which should be set to `151` for receiving addresses and `137` for senders.

There's probably more that is needed, I would read the existing database and just go through it field by field and make sure you're covering things in there that aren't `null` or `0`.