# ContentResolver query is throwing a nullpointerException

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm writing an MMS/SMS application on a rooted Android 2.3.3 htc incredible S with sense 2.1.
Now, while trying to receive a certain contacts list of SMS/MMS's I get a FC in the query.

here's some code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/"+String.valueOf(thread_id));
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
Cursor c= cr.query(uri,null,null,null,null);    //crashing here
```

logcat:

```
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.uiu.messaging/com.uiu.messaging.ContactMessageChain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1033)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1328)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:160)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:372)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:408)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:264)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at com.uiu.messaging.Data.getContactChain(Data.java:319)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at com.uiu.messaging.ContactMessageChain.onCreate(ContactMessageChain.java:138)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
05-22 15:24:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(32087):    ... 11 more
```

All permissions are accounted for.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

After following Mike's suggestion I receive the following error in the logcat:

```
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.uiu.messaging/com.uiu.messaging.ContactMessageChain}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "*": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date * 1 AS normalized_date, NULL AS * FROM sms WHERE (htc_category= 0 AND thread_id = 25 AND (type != 3 AND type > 0)) UNION SELECT DISTINCT date * 1000 AS normalized_date, NULL AS * FROM pdu LEFT JOIN pending_msgs ON pdu._id = pending_msgs.msg_id WHERE (htc_category= 0 AND thread_id = 25 AND msg_box != 3 AND (msg_box > 0 AND msg_box != 3 AND (m_type = 128 OR m_type = 132 OR m_type = 130))) ORDER BY normalized_date ASC)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1033)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "*": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date * 1 AS normalized_date, NULL AS * FROM sms WHERE (htc_category= 0 AND thread_id = 25 AND (type != 3 AND type > 0)) UNION SELECT DISTINCT date * 1000 AS normalized_date, NULL AS * FROM pdu LEFT JOIN pending_msgs ON pdu._id = pending_msgs.msg_id WHERE (htc_category= 0 AND thread_id = 25 AND msg_box != 3 AND (msg_box > 0 AND msg_box != 3 AND (m_type = 128 OR m_type = 132 OR m_type = 130))) ORDER BY normalized_date ASC)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:158)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:372)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:408)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:264)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at com.uiu.messaging.Data.getContactChain(Data.java:318)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at com.uiu.messaging.ContactMessageChain.onCreate(ContactMessageChain.java:138)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
05-22 16:31:46.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     ... 11 more
```

I have no idea what's wrong with the SQL statement...

Comment: Attaching the stack trace from logcat is usually wise.

Comment: What is the value of the uri before calling query?

Comment: as written above the thread_id is a long

Comment: This seems to crash on a Galaxy Note 2 with Android 4.3. The error is `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: normalized_date (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM threads ORDER BY normalized_date desc` . How can you determine if the normalized_date column does not exist? I have tested this on other versions of android without an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, fixed it. the trick was to enter actual column names into the projection. Seems like the bug was android's after all.

Answer (score 1):

According to this other answer the second parameter shouldn't be null(although the documentation says that is a valid value), try

```
final String[] projection = new String[]{"*"};
Cursor query = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

[original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012287/how-to-read-mms-data-in-android)

Comment: This is incorrect. The [**documentation**](http://tinyurl.com/cl7ygch) states that the `projection` argument is "The list of columns to put into the cursor. If `null` all columns are included."

Comment: @AlexLockwood Yeah I saw that in the documentation but since he was getting an error, thought about the possibility of a bug in Android.  I believe if he adds a projection besides "*" it would return an empty set without an error, further suggesting a possible android bug.

Comment: I've used `ContentProvider`s before and can assure you it's not a bug in the documentation... passing `null` is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I'm not sure why that question you posted says you need to pass `*`... this sort of SQL syntax is mostly abstracted by the Android SDK.

Comment: @AlexLockwood as I referenced in the answer, it is based on another post on SO where they claim that the second param can't be null, even though the documentation claims it can be.

Comment: Well it seemed to have helped by user's answer so let's agree to disagree.

Comment: Hmm... that seems very odd. I have never had this problem... weird!