# Querying the MMS-SMS conversation

Tags: android, mms

I am implementing the methods discussed here [How to Read MMS Data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012287/how-to-read-mms-data-in-android)
Here is the snippet.

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
final String[] projection = new String[]{"*"};
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");
Cursor query = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

When I try to get the data through the cursor, I do not get the IDs of the MMS messages. I only get the IDs of the SMS messages. I have two MMS in my inbox and their address "number" do not show up.

Comment: [READ_sms/mms_programmatically](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2011/10/listen-sms-mms-programmatically-android.html) may help you..