# Query does not get MMS messages

Tags: android, sms, mms

I am implementing the method discussed here [How to Read MMS Data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012287/how-to-read-mms-data-in-android). Here is the code snippet:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
final String[] projection = new String[]{"*"};
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");
Cursor query = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

When I try to get the data through the cursor, I do not get the IDs of the MMS messages. I only get the IDs of the SMS messages.

Comment: This is likely to fail in Samsung devices like Galaxy S3 with a NullPointerException from the ContentProvider :(

Only solution for that was to change the URI to "content://mms-sms/conversations/?simple=true"

Answer (score 0):

change your code as:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

final String[] projection = new String[]{"*"};

Uri MMSSMS_FULL_CONVERSATION_URI = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations");  

Uri uri  = MMSSMS_FULL_CONVERSATION_URI.buildUpon().  
     appendQueryParameter("simple", "true").build(); 

Cursor query = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

My code is right. It just needs this code to get the id of the messages

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
```