# Unrecognized URI: content://mms-sms/

Tags: android, database, sms, mms

I want to get all MMS and SMS message records at the same time, but `mms-sms` seems to be an  *Unrecognized URI* which I copy from android's source...

```
getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms"), projections, null, null, null);
```

Here is the stacktrace, after using code below:

code:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");
    Cursor query = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

log:

```
08-20 18:02:26.696: E/AndroidRuntime(2637): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 18:02:26.696: E/AndroidRuntime(2637): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 18:02:26.696: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1328)
08-20 18:02:26.696: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:160)
08-20 18:02:26.696: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
08-20 18:02:26.696: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:330)
08-20 18:02:26.696: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)...
```

Comment: Where do you see a Unrecognized URI exception? Oo

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Sorry about that, and will delete it soon after someone read.

Comment: Again, there is no Unrecognized URI exception in your stacktrace...

Comment: It is caused by these two code, after I comment the others: Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");
  Cursor query = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);

Comment: Maybe I should test them on some device else. thanks all the same.

Comment: I got overwhelmed, works on LG, but not Moto.

Comment: buddy visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/6446831/1218762 you will get answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change "content://mms-sms/conversations/" to "content://mms-sms/conversations"
It should work.

Comment: they are the same thing! take a look this as @Rstar mentioned:  stackoverflow.com/a/6446831/1218762