# Android: back-up messages and files programmatically

Tags: java, android, backup

Is it possible to back-up messages (SMS, MMS, email) and files (both on internal and external memory) then restore it using the same application without having to root/jailbreak the device? Either possible or not, what approach will I consider? [Kindly support with SSCCE, Thanks]

I am consider Android 2.2 (Froyo) as my base platform.

---

UPDATE: Jan. 30, 2013

Update my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it too much of a longshot just to quote this question for the bounty?

[How to Read MMS Data in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012287/how-to-read-mms-data-in-android)

Be sure to request the READ_SMS permission in your manifest.

Comment: What else do you need? I gave a link to get the message, do you want code on how to write that data to disk?

Comment: I need how I could make the back-up of all of the messages and restore it. Going to update my question (I failed to mention such thing, sorry.) Sorry for such bounty, that's only what I have ATM.

Comment: So, I'm not going to write all that code for you, I strongly suggest you take a look at [SMSBackup+](https://github.com/jberkel/sms-backup-plus/tree/master/src/com/zegoggles/smssync)'s code to see how it's done. Try looking at SmsBackupService.java and SmsRestoreService.java . StackOverflow isn't a "write me this code for bounty please" website.

Comment: Sorry about that but that is what I implied basing from your answer. Yet this help me figure-out to solve one of the two problems (I guess - for now). But I still can't accept this unless the other one is given. I can accept quotes/links supporting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to back-up messages (SMS, MMS, email) and files (both on internal and external memory) then restore it using the same application without having to root/jailbreak the device?

Not for all of that. In fact, not even for most of that.

Some things have public, documented means of loading and saving data, such as content providers documented in the Android SDK. Many of those are not designed to be used for backup/restore purposes. For example, if you tried to back up and restore contacts, since many of those contacts are actually synchronized from other sources (e.g., Facebook), you could screw things up royally.

Some things have undocumented, unsupported means of loading and saving data, such as the SMS content provider. Since you have no way of accurately predicting the behavior across multiple devices, trying to implement a backup/restore regime using these sources is impractical IMHO.

Everything else on internal storage is inaccessible to you, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: True that this can be a concern regarding privacy and security issues but I am just wondering how some were able to pull this off?

Comment: @Dr.Java: Full backup software requires root.

Comment: Is there a way for me to pull this off? With the awareness of privacy and security concerns?

Comment: @Dr.Java: Pull *what* off?

Comment: I mean the backup apps currently available on the market. I am curious how they were able to build it.

Comment: @Dr.Java: As I wrote, full backup software requires root (or the assistance of the Android SDK and a desktop, using `adb backup`). If you can name any app "available on the market" that advertises full backup without root or `adb backup`, post it here, so I can figure out what security holes they are exploiting and get them fixed.