# Can you link from your application to open Android native messaging inbox?

Tags: android

We have an application that handles the sending of SMS to a recipient to a lower rate than most operators. However, due to permission restrictions we wont be able to show incoming SMS.

Therefore we had an idea if we easily could link from our application to open the native inbox for relative easy access to the conversation you're in.

Is anyone aware of whether it's possible to link to the Android native inbox, and preferably link it so that pressing "Back" will take the user back to the application? An additional side question, if this is possible then can we also request a toast to show when opening the native inbox to say something along the lines of "Press 'Back' to go back to application"?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the sms box via `Intent`, but I think that you can do something better. You can get the List off SMS/MMS and do what you want in your own applicaiton. Take a look at [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012287/how-to-read-mms-data-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, requiring the SMS/MMS list will force additional app permissions to be added, right? I don't see anything mentioned about it in the other post so that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Oh.. I really do no if you need the permission to this code work fine, apparently yeah.. You can't ask for the permission?

Comment: Or try to launch SMS app with `Intent iLaunch = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
  startActivity(iLaunch);`

Comment: Hmm interesting suggestions indeed. @gabrielaugustodm, we could ask for the permission. The problem then is that the app will not longer be able to auto update, the permission is "too severe" by that point to update without the user agreeing to it. And there is a discussion going on whether that is acceptable or not. This is for a solution where we don't get to add the permission.

Comment: I got it.. this is a problem in the applications that I worked also but the system and his politics if based on the user pleasure. Sometimes we can dodge this, but certainly it's not good. When you make programmation "not official", probably the method that you used will be blocked in  others versions of Android, you do not wanna this, right?

Comment: no that's right. we need to produce the most seamless solution possible, that is also compatible between all Android 3.X-4.X, maybe even 2.X (not sure about those versions..)