# Fetch Image from MMS - Android

Tags: android, mms

I need to fetch image from MMS that having txt and image.

```
query.getString(cPart.getColumnIndex("ct");
```

...returns `text/plain` type.

Don't show image type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each MMS message has multiple parts stored in the `content://mms/part/` table. Some parts may be text, some may be images and other media types. Once you have the ID of the MMS you want to read, query all parts:

```
Cursor query = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://mms/part", null, "mid = " + mmsID, null, null);
```

If the MMS contains and image, it will have a part whose content type is an image type.

```
if(query.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String type = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex("ct"));
        if(type.equals("image/bmp") || type.equals("image/jpeg") || ...) 
            //Read the image
    while(query.moveToNext());
}
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6446831/797390) for more information about reading MMSs.

Comment: when i change this it shows complie error.. 'The method query(Uri, String[], String, String[], String) in the type ContentResolver is not applicable for the arguments (Uri, null, String[], null, null)'

Comment: Yea... I passed a string array instead of a string. I'll change it.

Comment: ya. i already give that.. It only show the type as text/plain.. Not consider other part(image/jpg)