# Android - Query All MMS & SMS from Specific Thread_ID

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider, mms, android-cursor

How can I query *all* messages sent by a specific address?

**I couldn't find my answer on StackOverflow after many days of searching.**

I'm currently getting all messages like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, ("thread_id = " + ThreadID), null, "date ASC");
```

But this only returns SMS messages (no MMS). I tried changing `content://sms/` to `content://mms-sms/` but that was unrecognized. I also tried to query `content://mms-sms/conversations/xxx` where `xxx` is the thread_id but that just gave me a NullPointerException.

I've been searching for a solution to this for days. Other SMS apps such as Go SMS and Sliding Messaging can do it perfectly but I just can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012287/how-to-read-mms-data-in-android?rq=1    This might be of help !

Comment: Seen it and I tried what it suggests, still no help.

Comment: @Pkmmte  u resolved your issue ?

Answer (score 3):

A `null` projection argument to `content://mms-sms/conversations/xxx` is what's causing the `NullPointerException` --- if you explicitly project the columns you want (e.g, `{"address", "body", "date"}`), it should work just fine.

However, querying by `thread_id` isn't strictly selecting based on the address the message is sent from; if you want that, you should probably look in `content://sms/inbox` (which ignores messages you've sent) and use selection arguments to query for the address you're interested in:

```java
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, "address=?", {targetedAddress}, "date ASC");
```