# Get all sms/mms sent to one specific phone number in Android

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to get the list of all the sms/mms sent to one particular phone number. I have been able to do this by getting at least one sms/mms from that number and then based on the thread_id, I get the sent sms/mms to that phone number. However, I have not been able to filter Sent SMS/MMS based on the destination number given I am the sender. Any ideas ? I know that Android doesn't support interaction with SMS/MMS officially, at least, not up to API level 18.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, although android doesn't support sms and mms interaction you can query the content provider responsible for the handling of sms and mms data.

Since you can query the content provider related to sms and mms data you can know the sent sms and mms and the destination of that sms and mms message.

I didn't flaged this answer as duplicate because the idea behind it is slightly different from the following link:

You can use this answer to build what you want to achieve:

[How to Read MMS Data in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012287/how-to-read-mms-data-in-android)

The only difference is that you dont want to query the content provider for unread messages like i did but for sent messages and include the destination number