When i send mms message along with text i can't able to retrive the text message in Android 14
i have fold device android 14 , recently  i can't able to retrive the text message which i send along with mms ,
below code I am using this  code to retrive the text message from MMS , when i try to debug the  column doesn't contains text message , is it os issue or i am doing something wrong ?
I have tried this method  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012287/how-to-read-mms-data-in-android][link] but it's not working , still i am getting null or empty values from system


 private fun getMmsText(id: String): String? {
        val uri = Uri.parse("content://mms/$id/part")
        val projection = arrayOf("_id", "text")
        val selection = "ct='text/plain'"
        val selectionArgs: Array<String>? = null
        val sortOrder = null

        application.applicationContext.contentResolver.query(
            uri,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            sortOrder
        )
            ?.use { cursor ->
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("text"))
                }
            }

        return null
    }



